# \Eloquent\Model::Create method returns null with status code OK

Tags: php, laravel

Create method doesn't work as expected. Always return OK status, with null data and no insert in db. No error displayed unfortunatelly so i don't know what to do.

```
protected function addBooking(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();


    if ($this->validator($data)->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $this->validator($data)->errors());
    }

    Booking::create($data);

    return $data;

}
```

This is the migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('booker_id')->nullable(false)->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('classroom_id')->nullable(false)->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('color')->default("#ff0000");
        $table->string('file')->default(NULL);
        $table->string('start')->nullable(false);
        $table->string('end')->nullable(false);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('booker_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('classroom_id')->references('id')->on('classrooms');
    });
}
```

The model

```
  class Booking extends Model
    {
    protected $fillable = [
        'booker_id', 'classroom_id', 'name', 'color', 'file', 'start', 'end'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    protected $casts = [
    ];
}
```

How i send the request

```
{
  "booker_id": 10,
  "classroom_id": 4,
  "name": "Microsoft",
  "start": "2019-04-25 14:45",
  "end": "2019-04-25 16:45",
  "color": "#ff0000",
  "file": "test"
}
```

Comment: Can you try `dd($data)` before your `Booking::create($data)`?

Comment: if it was returning null then $data is null because you are returning $data not  Booking::create($data) so I think you could abort request before 'return $data' to check if it was even reaching this line.

Comment: the output of dd($data) is to large to post it here

Comment: could you use request->only instead of request->all and return  Booking::create($data);?

Comment: unfortunately it's the same thing

Comment: Have you tried to remove the validator code?

Comment: Yes, still not working. Is this because of the the foreign keys i have on the model? Is there something special I have to do when i have relationships?

Comment: No, nothing special have you tried $data=[fill the data manually here] instead of $data=$request->all()

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: but it would at least print out the array right (return $data line) ?

Comment: Before ::create $data is ok, has the correct values, but after ::create it is null i guess since I can't event var_dump it.

Comment: anything in `laravel.log`?

Comment: Yeah, apparently looking in laravel.log really helped. The problem was `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` which basically means i'm stupid. One of the values of the foreign keys didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

// You should use form request for validate data. and move all your business logic to model

```
protected function addBooking(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();


    if ($this->validator($data)->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $this->validator($data)->errors());
    }

    return Booking::create($data)->fresh();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a routing convention, if you are creating new item, the method name shoul be store().
I am using two ways of creating new element:
First this is shorter, and i add validation in StoreBooking

```
public function store( StoreBooking $request ) {
  $data = $request->all();
  $booking = Booking::query()->create( $data );
}
```

Loger based on laravel's documentation:

```
public function store( StoreBooking $request ) {
 $booking = new Booking();
 $booking->bookier_id = $request->bookier_id;
 /**
  add other items
 **/
 $booking->save();
}
```